# joining three tables in mysql with two conditions

Tags: mysql

This is the query:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM posts 
    JOIN posts_views_likes ON posts.postid = posts_views_likes.postid 
    JOIN shared_posts ON posts.postid = shared_posts.postid 
    WHERE posts.username = 'abbsmalone' or shared_posts.username = 'abbsmalone' 
    ORDER BY posts_views_likes.ratio DESC, posts.date
```

The problem is that the output only gives me results that match the second condition (where shared_posts.username = 'abbsmalone') but none that match the first. It works when I remove the third table from the equation so I'm assuming I'm not joining the three correctly?

Comment: My best guess is that you're intending on using left joins as opposed to standard (inner) joins, although it's really hard to tell without a sample of your data...

Comment: query without filters(where clause) to confirm tables are joined correctly. Probably posts where username = 'abbsmalone' does not have likes or is not shared (as inner join is being used).

Comment: Ah, you are correct, I needed LEFT JOIN. For some reason I was thinking LEFT JOIN was the default.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Inner Join, hence it will only give you result if all the join condition are satisfied.